# How can I share the pdf file to email by using pspdfkit?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to send the signed pdf to other's email. How can I do?

**My Code:**

```
@objc func handleUploadPDF() {
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Exhibit-A-SAMPLE-CONTRACT.pdf")
    let writableURL = copyFileURLToDocumentFolder(fileURL)
    let document = PSPDFDocument(url: fileURL)
    let configuration = PSPDFConfiguration { builder in
        builder.thumbnailBarMode = .scrollable
    }

    let pdfController = PDFViewController(document: document, configuration: configuration)
    present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: pdfController), animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you include `emailButtonItem` in `pdfViewController`'s navigation item's right bar button items array, like so:

```swift
@objc func handleUploadPDF() {
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Exhibit-A-SAMPLE-CONTRACT.pdf")
    let writableURL = copyFileURLToDocumentFolder(fileURL)
    let document = PSPDFDocument(url: fileURL)
    let configuration = PSPDFConfiguration { builder in
        builder.thumbnailBarMode = .scrollable
    }

    let pdfController = PDFViewController(document: document, configuration: configuration)
    pdfController.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([pdfController.emailButtonItem], animated: false)
    present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: pdfController), animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

[image]

For more details about how to customize the toolbar, please take a look at https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/customizing-the-interface/customizing-the-toolbar/

In the future, please reach out to our support portal at pspdfkit.com/support/request/ - we're happy to provide support there for our commercial SDK.